# User input in batch file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a batch file that looks like this, which takes a picture of a webpage and crops it:

```
cd C:\users\***\Downloads\IECapt-2008-06-10
IECapt --delay=10000 --url=http://test.com/picture.swf?id=1 --out="C:\users\***\My Documents\picture.png"
cd C:\users\***\My Documents
convert picture.png -trim picture.png

ftp -s:place_img.txt
```

I was wondering is there was a way that I could alter this script to accept user input to replace the URL and the file name with what the user inputted. For example, the user would input a URL and a file name and it would replace these things:

```
cd C:\users\***\Downloads\IECapt-2008-06-10
IECapt --delay=10000 --url=(((http://test.com/picture.swf?id=1))) --out="C:\users\***\My Documents\((picture)).png"
cd C:\users\***\My Documents
convert ((picture)).png -trim ((picture)).png

ftp -s:place_img.txt
```

(((URL being replaced)))

((File name being replaced))

**This is the "place_picture.txt" file:**

```
open test.com
username
pass
hash
bin
lcd c:\users\***\My Documents
cd public_html/test.com/test
put picture.png
bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this batch code works;

```
@echo off
set /p input=
if %input% == 1 goto ech
:ech
echo Here is your writed text;
echo %input%
pause
```

`set /p input=` includes input for batch.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind. One, you could easily set your batch file to [take arguments from the command line](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php), or two, [prompt for user input](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php) after the user runs the batch file.

I'm not sure how your place_picture.txt relates to the batch file, but I suspect there will need to be some processing done as well.